# request gopro clock wifi

Tags: wifi, httprequest, clock, gopro

I want to retrieve or set the value of the (unsynced) clock of my goprohero 3 silver edition programmatically through wifi.

- It runs a linux kernel
- It runs a cherokee web server available at 10.5.5.9.
- It can be ordered to do something like switch its capture mode or take a photo with GET httprequests such as

  ```
  http://10.5.5.9/camera/PW?t=password&p=%0
  ```

but I did not see any request for the clock. From what I've read port 22 is blocked and it is not possible to connect to the gopro through ssh.

Any idea how to that ? Thanks in advance.